# Calculating resistance, voltage and current in parallel circuit

Tags: parallel, homework

[image: parallel circuit]

I need help in solving these questions. I've tried to use Kirchhoff's law but this hasn't worked.
I have been having a lot of difficulty with the resistance and current calculations, would someone be able to help show me where I have made mistakes.

Comment: Why do you think that R1 and R2 have two different currents through each?

Comment: Show how you get 2.3 ohms for the total resistance. Why are you using Kirchoff when the question says Ohm's Law?

Comment: got the 2.3 by adding 1 divided by 1 plus 1 divided by 3 which equals 1.3, then did same method for the other two resistors and they bothe equaled 1, totaling both sides came out to 2.3.

Comment: But the 1 ohm and 3 ohm resistors are in series, therefore add. As do the two 2 ohm resistors. The two branches are then in parallel.

Comment: You also mention Kirchhoff's law. Using Kirchhoff's voltage law, the voltage drop of \${R_{1}} + {R_{2}}\$ should be \$12V\$ and the voltage drop of \${R_{2}} + {R_{3}}\$ should also be \$12V\$

Answer (score 1):

You're calculating total resistance incorrectly. Parallel resistance is \$ \frac{1}{R_{T}} = \frac{1}{R_{1}} + \frac{1}{R_{2}} \cdots  \$
Where you get the \$(1+1+1)/3 \$ from, I'm not entirely sure.

\${R_{1}}\$ and \${R_{2}}\$ are in series. These are in parallel with \${R_{3}}\$ and \${R_{4}}\$ which are in series.
First thing you want to do is simplify each branch into a single resistor. As \${R_{1}}\$ and \${R_{2}}\$ are in series we can simply add them. So the total resistance in our first branch is \$4\Omega\$.
If we do the same with our second branch (So \${R_{3}} + {R_{4}}\$) then we can see the total resistance in our second branch is also \$4\Omega\$.
Now we have a circuit that looks like this:

[image]

(By the way, whichever teacher drew this needs to go back to school themselves imo. Nobody would ever draw a parallel circuit like this, [Google 'parallel resistor circuit to see my point'](https://www.google.com/search?q=parallel%20resistor%20circuit&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwijkMz7tLfSAhVqDcAKHadxAVcQ_AUICCgB&biw=1920&bih=960))

Now that you've got this simplified circuit, finding parallel resistance is a lot simpler. Using the equation \$ \frac{1}{R_{T}} = \frac{1}{R_{1}} + \frac{1}{R_{2}} \cdots  \$ we can put our values in to get \$\frac{1}{R_{T}} = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4}\$, this comes out to be \$\frac{1}{R_{T}} = 0.5\$.
However, we don't want \$\frac{1}{R_{T}}\$ we just want \${R_{T}}\$ so we have to invert the equation like so. \$\frac{1}{R_{T}} = 0.5 \rightarrow {R_{T}}=\frac{1}{0.5}\$. This gives a value of \${R_{T}} = 2\Omega\$.
(As there is only 2 resistances you can also use \$\frac{R_{a}\times R_{b}}{R_{a}+R_{b}} \$ but it's personal choice)

You should be able to do the rest of the questions now with ease if you follow Krishn's advice in the other answer

Comment: It seems to me that the circuits in this sort of exercise are often drawn in a way intended to confuse the student.  Re-drawing the circuit in a more conventional arrangement will often clarify the actual connections.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if look at your text book carefully, you will probably get a clear idea of solving this.

I'll give you hints to solve it:

1) As it is mentioned in the question itself *parallel circuit*, find the total resistance of your circuit using **Parallel combination of resistors**.

2) After calculating total resistance, you can easily find the *total current* in flowing in your circuit using **Ohms law**.

3) Using **current division principle**, you can calculate the *currents flowing through different parallel branches*.

and finally,

4) Using **Voltage division principle**, you can calculate the *voltage drops across different resistors*.

Comment: I got the 2.3 by adding 1 divided by 1 plus 1 divided by 3 which equals 1.3, then did same method for the other two resistors and they bothe equaled 1, totaling both sides came out to 2.3.

Comment: @MontrellLugeneHill As Chu commented, the resistors R1, R2 are in series, so add them. Similarly R3 and R4 are also in series. Now you will have two resistors which are in parallel. Calculate the the total resistance of these parallel resistors. (2.3 ohm is wrong).

Comment: @MontrellLugeneHill A tip to remember is that the current flowing in a series circuit is the same across every component (So \${R_{1}}\$ and \${R_{2}}\$ will have the same current. Also \${R_{3}}\$ and \${R_{4}}\$ will have the same current)